# How to close only JDialog and have JFrame still usable

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jdialog

I've a `JFrame` and a `JPanel` is added in. When I click o a button in the panel, a `JDialog` (named `choiceDialog`) appears. When I click on a particular button on the dialog I just want it to close.

I would want **the dialog closed and the frame usable**. Is it possible?

I tried to hide the dialog with `setVisible(false)` but it hid both the dialog and frame. Then I tried to do `choiceDialog.dispose()` but I lost both the elements again. At that point I found a way to set the Frame again visible but not usable.

Can anyone help me please? I don't really know what to do.

Here's the relevant code:

```
if (dimField.isEnabled()){
    String dimFieldText = dimField.getText();
    if (dimFieldText.equals("") || !isNumeric(dimFieldText)){ //if there's an error when filling the options in the JDialog             
        errorLabel = new JLabel(noDim, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        /*other stuff
             ...
         */
    }else{ //if it's all ok: I want the JDialog close but the JFrame to be usable                   
        JFrame topFrame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this); //to catch the JFrame istance
        choiceDialog.dispose();
        topFrame.setVisible(true); //to make the JFrame visible again
        //choiceDialog.setVisible(false);
    }
```

Comment: *`topFrame.setVisible(true); //to make the JFrame visible again`* Why is the top frame ever set ***invisible***? I would make the dialog modal, and specify the frame as the parent. That way, the user can see the frame but not interact with it until the dialog is closed. General tip: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I see you added the 'interested code' (which most would call the 'relevant code'), but an MRE / SSCCE is much more useful. It should only take 20-40 lines of code to create one.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes I meant "relevant code". 2nd stuff: I already set the dialog as modal (in the method where I set the JDialog). How can I specify the frame as the parent? I found only the getParent() method.

Comment: @AndrewThompson this is the code I used to set the JDialog:  ```public void setChoiceDialog(String currentFile){
  choiceDialog = new JDialog();
  choiceDialog.setTitle("Impostazioni");
  choiceDialog.setVisible(true);
  choiceDialog.setModal(true);
  choiceDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  choiceDialog.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,4));
  choiceDialog.pack();} ```

Comment: @AndrewThompson and then I just added some components as TextFields, JRadioButtons and so on

Comment: @AndrewThompson I set the topFrame visible because after the execution of the instruction ```choiceDialog.dispose();``` it becomes invisible

Comment: @AndrewThompson I find out the problem. It was the setModal() property. I just deleted it and now the JDialog works well! Thank you for your advices. I will take advantage of them in the next questions

Answer (score 0):

You are setting topFrame to be the window ancestor of the button,  which is the dialog itself. You need to get the window ancestor of the dialog instead. That assumes that when you created the dialog you specified the main frame as its parent rather than using the no-argument JDialog constructor.

Comment: ok now I declared topFrame in the method to set the JDialog and put it as a parameter of the JDialog constructor. What I have to do doing ```choiceDialog.getParent();``` ?

Comment: I find out the problem. It was the setModal() property. I just deleted it and now the JDialog works well!